# npm i puppeteer has Failed to set up Chromium r756035

Tags: windows, npm, puppeteer, chromium

While trying to install puppeteer with: `npm i puppeteer` getting this error. My Node version is v12.16.3. I'm on a windows machine.

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r756035! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:608:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1514:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Red Viper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:116:19)
    at fetchBinary (C:\Users\Red Viper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer\install.js:148:8)
    at download (C:\Users\Red Viper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer\install.js:54:9) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'storage.googleapis.com',
  port: 443,
  localAddress: undefined
}
```

Comment: The govt blocked google storage api. You have to use vpn, or actually set the env variable to run puppeteer normally.

Comment: but I'm able to use puppeteer-core,  the problem exists only when I try to install puppeteer and more specifically when it tries to download chromium .

Answer (score 8):

use `--unsafe-perm`

It works for me!

```
npm i puppeteer -g --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 3):

Run following command from terminal:

Mac:

```
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD='true'
```

Windows:

```
SET PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD='true'
```

Both will set environment variable and you should be fine with execution

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason was that this address was banned in my country. I had to use a proxy to avoid this error.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you're behind a proxy, may be you can contact your network/security admin in your organization.
This was the case for me, and the issue didn't appear in my home network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).